# Determine if a UserDefault property has been set, or if the value returned for a property is a registered property value

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I am using UserDefaults to store my app preferences.  Upon initialization the preference properties and values are created, the `defaults` object is initialized using a suite name (my app name), and then I convert my preferences to a dictionary and register the preferences in the `defaults` object.

What I would like to know is if I request `defaults.object(forKey: "someKey")` how can I know if that key has been set due to a preferences change, or it is a registered default value?  I have read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) and I did not see anything that would allow me to determine that.

The dictionary created for the defaults is not persisted in memory, but I guess if needed to I could make it a global property and then compare the returned value to the dictionary value and if the values are them same I could assume the value is being returned from the registered defaults.  I just wanted to ask before I make that code change.

Comment: @VictorHenrique this does not appear correct from my observations.  Once defaults.register is called, even by using `defaults.object(forKey:)` the default value is returned, not nil.

Comment: I tried getting a dictionary representation of the userdefaults, but that even returns the registered properties and values.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting it to a default value. Could you wrap the user defaults and return the default value if it is not set. Only set the user defaults when the user sets it.

So now, if the user defaults value is nil. You can return your default value and know that it is the default.

If the user defaults value is not nil. You can return that value and know it is like that because the user set it. (Even if it happens to be the same as the default).

Comment: Hmmm...  Okay, so if I understand your answer correctly, I would need to make all my preference properties optionals, and then set each property to nil before registering them?  Doesn't that essentially defeat the purpose of registering default properties and their values?

Comment: Why do you need to register the default values in the first place?

Comment: I set default preferences for how the app works.  I then register those settings in UserDefaults and refer to UserDefaults any time I work with a configurable property.  This way, if the user changes a preference, it does not matter, because UserDefaults will pick up any changes.  I wanted to know this when I export the app settings to JSON because I did not want to export any properties that had not been modified by the user.  I think I figured it out using `Mirror` on my appPreferences object and a dictionaryRepresentation of the UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

```
if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "KEY") != "DEFAULT VALUE" { 
 ///if not default value
} else {
   //default value
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: From the question “Upon initialization the preference properties and values are created”. So the value would not be nil as it is set to the default value to begin with.

Comment: @Fogmeister ok but could you not also jsut check if it is the defualt value ? instead of NIL ?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri, right.  If I set each preference property to nil before registering it, that is just defeating the purpose of registering default values, IMO.

Comment: I think this is what I will eventually have to do.  Make my defaultsDictionary that is used to register the defaults initially a global property and then refer to that dictionary whenever I need to know if the default returned is in fact a default value or if the user has changed the preference value.